# What is proper punctuation & capitalization for the first sentence of a block quotation if only the 2nd half of sentence from the source is included?

Tags: capitalization, quotations, ellipses

Should an ellipsis be used at the beginning of a block quote, in which the first sentence of the multi sentence quote is only quoting half (the 2nd half) of the original quoted sentence?

In other words I see the indented block quote beginning like this:

> in it we see the xxxxxxxxx

rather than this:

> ...in it we see the xxxxxxx

The context of the quote is not a completion of an introductory sentence, but is a quote introduced by a colon such this: "The author says the following about this topic:"

I'm thinking that first sentence should either begin as

> ...in it we see the xxxxxxxx

or

> [I]n it we see the xxxxxxxx

But starting with a small case letter without any ellipsis looks odd, and doesn't seem right.  Unless there is some modern style which allows that.   What is acceptable?  And not acceptable?

Hmmm, what happened to the answers and comments that were associated here with my question the past 2 days?  This afternoon I now only see the question but none of the answers or comments which have been displayed the past 2 days.

Comment: Can you please some (much) better examples?